# How to CSS style a table such that cells is at most 30% of screen height and use a scroll bar when it's taller?

Tags: css, css-tables

How to CSS style a table such that

- a cell is at most 30% of screen height
- use a vertical scroll bar when it's taller than 30% of screen height
- don't use a scroll bar if it's shorter than 30% of screen height
- works in Firefox and Chrome

#### EDIT

I tried

```
tr td {
    max-height:30%;
    height:auto !important;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

and several variants with no luck.  The tall cells came out taller than 30% of screen height.

#### An alternative question if the original is too hard:

I can accept any way to present the content of a large cell, for example, if the big cell can be clapsed and reopen by a button or something, and the scrollbar isn't absolutely  required, as long as the cell height is at most 30% of the screen; I.e. the main goal is to avoid having a cell so tall that the whole screen is showing a part of one cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason it has to be 30% as opposed to a set height? I was able to achieve the effect I think you're going for by throwing the content in a div

```
tr td div.box {
   max-height:200px;
   overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: This somehow doesn't work for me.  Neither in Chrome, nor in Firefox.

Comment: I've just made this [(click here)](http://jsfiddle.net/TDaaL/), tried it in Firefox and Chrome and it works for me. What versions of browsers do you have? If this won't work can I ask if your height has to be in percent and if you need to apply styling directly to the table cell, rather than adding a div inside it?

Comment: It adds an redundant scroll bar even if the cell's content is not tall.  Is there a way to avoid that?